# Testing React components - mount vs shallow and simulating events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I have the following React components that I'm trying to test by simulating entry into the input field with id=componentCount. I started using React for the first time less than one week ago, so this framework is very new to me and any help would be appreciated.
I'm also using Semantic UI React for the CSS framework, hence the Form.Group and Form.Input tags

```
export class SoftwareForm extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        componentCount: 0
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Form id='softwareForm'>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Input label='Name' placeholder='Component Name' id='componentName' type='text'/>
                <Form.Input label='Description' placeholder='Component Description' id='componentDescription' type='text'/>
                <Form.Input name='componentCount'
                            label='Count'
                            placeholder='Count'
                            id='componentCount'
                            type='number'
                            min='0'
                            value={this.state.componentCount}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

}

**Test script**

```
describe('<SoftwareForm />', () => {
    it('Count field accepts text input', () => {
        const softwareFormComponent = mount(<SoftwareForm />);
        const countField = softwareFormComponent.find('#componentCount');
        countField.simulate('change', {target: {value: 3}});
        expect(softwareFormComponent.state('componentCount')).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

The above test script uses mount for full rendering, but I get the following error, "Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 4 found instead."

If I use a shallow mount, the test output is the following

```
Expected value to be (using ===):
  3
Received:
  0
```

This tells me that the simulate method is not working as expected.

Several questions:

1. Can a shallow render be used in this scenario since I can use the find method to search for the  element with the 'componentCount' id attribute or is a full render with a mount necessary since I'm trying to manipulate an input element which is a child of the Form.Group?
2. Regardless of the answer the question 1, when mount is used, the wrapper that is returned contains 4 nodes - what are these 4 nodes and which one am I supposed to call simulate on if a full render is in fact needed in this case? 
   I'm struggling due to not having a clear understanding of the structure of the wrapper object that is returned by either shallow or mount.
3. The idea of the last two statements in the test script is to simulate the change to the value of the number in the input field, have the onChange event handler trigger an update of the componentCount state value and then the perform a comparison using the assert statement. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answering your questions:

1. You could use mount, which create test on a full DOM rendering and it is ideal for use cases where you have components that may interact with DOM APIs, or may require the full lifecycle in order to fully test the component.
2. You can see that find returns using `.debug()`.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more attempts, I was able to get the test to work.

1. A shallow mount ended up being sufficient in this case even though I was interacting with input DOM element.
2. The simulate method used in the test script was changed to the following, 
   "countField.simulate('change',{
           target: { name: "componentCount", value: 3 } });